# What is the area of a pixellated surface?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, discrete-mathematics

Recently after playing hours of Minecraft (and generating block volumes), a question popped up in my head: Is it possible to easily (by hand in a reasonable amount of time) determine the surface area of an arbitrary function? For instance, if you were to take the function $y=x^2$, and move it onto a graph with discrete coordinate values (with non-integer function values being rounded accordingly - something like $\text{Int}(y)=x^2$ for $[\text{Int}(a),\text{Int}(b)]$ ? Extending that further, like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80726/calculate-volume-and-surface-area-of-a-voxel-based-sphere) would it be possible to find the volume of some equation or solid of revolution and in addition the surface area? In other words, could you calculate the area of a function using the rectangle method with midpoint approximation and equal width rectangles?

If these are not possible, can one find some sort of approximation of this area/volume more accurate than that of the integral it seems to represent?
Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps use the [Euler-Maclaurin formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula) to estimate the discrete sum by an integral?

Answer (score 1):

I would propose using the rectangle method described here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangle_method

The only problem is I'm not sure what to input for N given a generic volume. Maybe someone else can elaborate on this.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! This is better left as a comment, although you do not yet have enough reputation for that. Regards

Comment: Oh, allright, I guess that's because it's not a complete answer? I hadn't even thought of it so thanks for the advice.

Comment: It would help if you could provide more details on the Rectangle Method and how it would apply. Also, you are correct as it is not complete. I am not the police, just trying to comment on why there were no up-votes and making recommendations. Regards